# Running through complex json and match text

Tags: php, json

I want to run through reddit comments and match the json with a specific text:

I tried the following

```
$str = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json'));
foreach ($str as $comments) {
    //dd($comments->data->children);
    foreach ($comments->data->children as $comment) {
        if ($comment->body_html == 'You') {
            print_r($comment);
        } else {
            print_r($comment);
        }
    }
}
```

However,  I  get the following error message:

```
  [ErrorException]                      
  Trying to get property of non-object  


Exception trace:
 () at /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/Console/Commands/reddit.php:58
 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/Console/Commands/reddit.php:58
 App\Console\Commands\reddit->handle() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:507
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:169
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:155
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:794
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:186
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:107
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/artisan:36
```

I expected to use `$comments->data->children` to access the `body_html` tag, but it does not work. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Can you try this first: `$data=file_get_contents('https://www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json'); print $data;`? This will help to see whether you’re getting a proper JSON string.

Comment: @Manngo Yes I am getting a proper json string back.

Comment: What do you get if you then try `print_r($str);`? The question is whether you’re getting the structure you’re expecting.

Comment: In the two answers so far, you get two conflicting options as to whether you have an array or an object. It could be either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, str is not an array but an object. That's how it works :

```
$str = file_get_contents('https://www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json');
$comments = json_decode($str);
foreach ($comments->data->children as $comment) {
        if ($comment->data->body_html == 'You') {
            print_r($comment);
        } else {
            print_r($comment);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Output of `json_decode` function in this case is an array, not an object. so you can't access it by `$comments->data->children`. Instead you can access it via: `$comments["data"]["children"]`.

If you want `json_decode` to produce objects as output, use the second parameter `true` for it:

```
$str = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json'), true);
```